# What is the best way to use javascript setInterval with long interval?

Tags: javascript

I have to update my list every 10 minutes, making an ajax call to the server, so wrote my code like this:

```
setInterval(function(){listRefresh();},600000);
```

I am thinking that the mobile device maybe wastes resources and that maybe there's a better way to do it.
Any advice?

Comment: It doesn't waste resource - it's very cheap to do this - it just schedules a timer.

Comment: Why not just `setInterval(listRefresh, 600000);`?

Comment: There is no problem using setInterval to this based on resources. However, I have never tested this on a mobile device for the period of time you are talking about. It will surely work as long as the user is on your page for 10 minutes. But I dont think it will work for example if he visits your page, turns off the screen and turns it back on after 9 minutes for example.

Comment: On mobile: iOS Chrome has another "time". The space/time continuum is misplaced into googleTime or so. ;) Runs slower, more than half the usual speed. No reading for you.

Comment: @DOCASAREL I never checked that but shouldn't that also happen for every browser/webview on iOS, as all of them have to use the HTML/JS engine of Apple.

Comment: @DOCASAREL what do you mean by "no reading for you" ?

Comment: @t.niese No, apparently not. I checked it. If I may humbly post a link: https://liebdich.biz, check it on iOS. I made browser sniffing to have it faster on Chrome; but you still can see a difference. Hey, found that, load it on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/32mbn/.

Comment: @Ferex I mean with "reading" I have no weblink or alike, giving respectability to my claim!

Comment: Ahah I tried, it seems that Chrome has milliseconds faster than Safari... but my test was on chrome and safari desktop, not mobile